# Is there a belongs_to 'sometimes' concept in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application where there are Products and a Cart. The Products will only belong_to the cart after they have been added to the Cart, and then the Cart will has_many Products. But before Products are added to the Cart, they are just in a stand alone model without associations. How do I capture this in rails?

I am confused about whether I should add the cart_id to the Products table, if they will only belong_to the Cart if and when they are added?

Answer (score 3):

The rails guide mentioned is definitely worth a look. It takes on just this problem.

I guess the question is: what does an individual instance of the class 'Product' represent, in your case? Is a product instance a **type** of a commodity, or a physical instance of that commodity?

The former probably makes more sense. In that case, the individual rows of the Products table would represent individual types of products -- and you would probably not want a cart_id column. Instead you'd want a join table, or preferably another model (Orders), to represent cases where a customer purchases individual products.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `LineItem` model which `belongs_to :cart` and `belongs_to :product`. Then in the cart you can do this:

```
has_many :products, :through => :line_items
```